# Recursively get data from Lists in LISP

Tags: list, recursion, lisp

LISP lists L1 and L2 are composed form random alphanumeric chars.

Appliyng recursion (and Variable Collector) generate list L3 by taking numbers from L1 and chars From L2

Example:

```
L1 = (1 a f 5 6 8)
L2 = (3 t 4 5 3 2)

Result: 
L3= (1 5 6 8 t)
```

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: is that homework?  What did you try?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a platform to solve your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like homework but here's how I'd do it with loop

```
(loop for i in L1 
      and j in L2
      if (numberp i)
         collect i into x
      if (symbolp j)
         collect j into y
      finally (return (append x y)))
```

Comment: huh?  i thought `L1` and `L2` were defined already, you posted it yourself.

Comment: I have not worked in Lisp and and I wrote this as I think of, but not sure if correct

Comment: well this looks clearly like homework to me then, am i right?  And it's `(defvar L1 '(1 a f 5 6 8)) (defvar L2 '(3 t 4 5 3 2))`

Answer (score 1):

Since this already have been answered, here's an alternative, a bit shorter way to do it:

```
(defparameter *l1* '(1 a f 5 6 8))
(defparameter *l2* '(3 t 4 5 3 2))

(append (delete-if #'symbolp *l1*)
    (delete-if #'numberp *l2*)) ; (1 5 6 8 t)
```

Comment: @wvcvw How to print the result in this form: Result is L3 (1 5 6 8 t)